# How to extract default-printer description (friendly name) in a macOS shell script (using a variable in awk)

Tags: variables, awk

I am trying to write a macOS shell script that can use the description (friendly name) of the default printer as a variable. I have got this far:

```
#!/bin/bash
default_printer_info=$(lpstat -d)
printer_name=$(echo "$default_printer_info" | awk '{print $4}')
lpstat -l -p | awk 'c&&!--c;/'"$printer_name"'/{c=4}' | grep Description: | cut -d " " -f2-
```

This does not work - although the last of these commands works correctly if I manually enter the content of the `$printer_name` variable into the `awk` string (for example, `PDFwriter`).

Can anyone help with getting the `$printer_name` variable into the `awk` string? I've tried various combinations of `awk -v VAR="$printer_name" ...` and similar efforts, without success.

EDIT: As requested, here is the output from `lpstat -d`:

`system default destination: Edward_Maine_LaserJet_400_MFP_M425dn`

and from `lpstat -l -p`:

```
printer Edward_Maine_LaserJet_400_MFP_M425dn is idle.  enabled since Thu Dec 21 15:53:40 2023
    Form mounted:
    Content types: any
    Printer types: unknown
    Description: Edward Maine LaserJet 400 MFP M425dn
    Alerts: none
    Location: 
    Connection: direct
    Interface: /private/etc/cups/ppd/Edward_Maine_LaserJet_400_MFP_M425dn.ppd
    On fault: no alert
    After fault: continue
    Users allowed:
        (all)
    Forms allowed:
        (none)
    Banner required
    Charset sets:
        (none)
    Default pitch:
    Default page size:
    Default port settings:
printer HP_LaserJet_P3010_Series is idle.  enabled since Thu Dec 21 12:46:40 2023
    Form mounted:
    Content types: any
    Printer types: unknown
    Description: Edward LaserJet P3015
    Alerts: none
    Location: 
    Connection: direct
    Interface: /private/etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_P3010_Series.ppd
    On fault: no alert
    After fault: continue
    Users allowed:
        (all)
    Forms allowed:
        (none)
    Banner required
    Charset sets:
        (none)
    Default pitch:
    Default page size:
    Default port settings:
```

SECOND EDIT: Expected output is:
`Edward Maine LaserJet 400 MFP M425dn`
See my comments below. macOS Sonoma seems to give empty output after I set a different default printer in System Settings, but gives the correct output after I switch back. The problem I'm facing seems to be in macOS.

Comment: `awk '... $0~var ...' var="$printer_name"` or `export printer_name; awk 'BEGIN{var=ENVIRON["printer_name"]} ... $0~var ...'` but are you sure `$printer_name` has the value you need? assuming no characters special to awk (like `/`, `+`, etc) your code looks like it should work

Comment: please update the question with the complete output from `lpstat -d` and `lpstat -l -p` (for your enviroment) and the expected output; it's probably possible to use just `lpstat -l -p` and a single `awk` script to replace all of the current code

Comment: The code you provided works with the data you provided (stored in files and then using `cat` instead of `lpstat`). So I'd guess either your data is actually different, or your code is.

Comment: @jhnc - Thank you. Something seems to be strange in my system. The code that I posted worked once, and then didn't work again during the hours I spent experimenting. When I read your comment, I tried it again and it worked. I apologize for wasting your time on this!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given that block of text at the bottom of your question as input.

Comment: @jhnc - Some more insight: when I change the default printer in System Settings, I get an empty string from this cide until I change the default printer again. So the problem seems not to be in my code but in macOS...

Comment: Your code has several bugs that will make it behave in different ways given various input content, environment variable settings, contents of the directory you run it from, etc so that's more likely to be the problem than an issue with macOS. Copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues.

Comment: @EdMorton - Of course you are right. shellcheck.net told me to add double quotes around $printer_info and that seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we combine the `lpstat` commands into `lpstat -dlp` (or `lpstat -d -l -p`), making sure we list the `-d` first, OP's ouput should look like:

```
system default destination: Edward_Maine_LaserJet_400_MFP_M425dn
printer Edward_Maine_LaserJet_400_MFP_M425dn is idle.  enabled since Thu Dec 21 15:53:40 2023
    Form mounted:
    Content types: any
    Printer types: unknown
    Description: Edward Maine LaserJet 400 MFP M425dn
...
printer HP_LaserJet_P3010_Series is idle.  enabled since Thu Dec 21 12:46:40 2023
    Form mounted:
    Content types: any
    Printer types: unknown
    Description: Edward LaserJet P3015
...
```

**NOTE:** I've placed OP's `lpstat` output in file `lpstat.dlp`

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
/system default destination:/    { defprt = $NF; next }       # make note of default printer name
$2==defprt && $1=="printer"      { print_desc = 1; next }     # if this is the line for the default printer then set flag (print_desc) to "1"
print_desc && $1=="Description:" { pos = index($0,": ")       # if print flag is set (==1) and this is a description line then find the ": " and ...
                                   print substr($0,pos+2)     # print the textual description to stdout
                                   exit
                                 }

' <(cat lpstat.dlp)
```

**NOTE:** OP will replace `<(cat lpstat.dlp)` with `<(lpstat -dlp)`

This generates:

```
Edward Maine LaserJet 400 MFP M425dn
```

Answer (score 3):

You may do this in a single command like this:

```bash
lpstat -l -p |
awk -F ': ' -v prt="$(lpstat -d | awk '{print $NF}')" '
c && !--c && /Description:/ {print $2; exit}
$0 ~ prt {c=4}'
```

Comment: That is perfect and brilliant. Thank you! Is it OK to ask next, how do I get the value of `prt` into a shell vairable??

Comment: @emendelson no, as that'd turn this into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), just ask a new question if you have to but there are millions of examples online (not to mention in your question and in this answer) showing how to save the output of a command in a variable.

Comment: @EdMorton - Understood, and now that I fixed the code according to your advice, I have no trouble getting the result into a variable. Thank you yet again!

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ { lpstat -d; lpstat -l -p; } |
    awk '
        name == "" { name=$NF; next }
        $1 == "printer" { isDflt = ($2 == name) }
        isDflt && sub(/^[[:space:]]*Description:[[:space:]]*/,"")
    '
Edward Maine LaserJet 400 MFP M425dn
```

You may be able to replace `{ lpstat -d; lpstat -l -p; }` with `lpstat -dlp`.

Comment: This version of the code produces blank output in macOS Sonoma, it seems.

Comment: Then the output of `lpstat -d; lpstat -l -p` must not look as you show in your question.

Comment: I tried it on another machine with a different set of printers; same blank output.  The two lpstat outputs are here: 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x958oizm0gafdbagdybk7/p.txt?rlkey=ae45lsmtyimt2kkvd2xl3gtaa&dl=0 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eg94zx8uui1kvtfh0lbb6/d.txt?rlkey=p4llm6azr0wj6ad7nyyntmuqv&dl=0

Comment: That is a good optimisation ++

Comment: @emendelson please don't add information in comments, and don;t provide it as links or images. Just put text in your question. I took a guess that maybe you have blank lines at the start of the input or some of the white space in your sample input isn't blank chars.